# How to get `indexOf()` cells value or convert an object to a String?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

My code is trying to "search" a spreadsheet for a row with two specific text lines. When the line is found within the first 30 rows a value of A1:A1 should replace a word in a document.

My problem is that I can not count the words with `indexOf()` because it needs a string and `getValue()/getDisplayValue()` produces an object/array. Furthermore js's `includes()` is not supported. Does someone know a solution?

```
function myFunction1() {

var tss = DocumentApp.openById("targetspreadsheet");
var docBody = tss.getBody();  


var sourcess =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("source spreadsheet");
var sources  = sourcess.getSheets()[0]; 


  for (var i = 1; i = 30 ; i++){

    var rowValues = sources.getRange(i, 1, 1, sources.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
    Logger.log(rowValues);

    if (rowValues.indexOf("Word1") >= 1 && rowValues.indexOf("Word2") >= 1){
      var name = sources.getRange("A1:A1").getValues();
      docBody.replaceText("TextToReplace", name)} 

    else {continue;}  

    }

}
```

Maybe I overlooked a solution while searching but so far I just found solutions working js and not google script. If so I'm sorry; otherwise if you can help me: thank you!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are searching individual rows for 2 specific words you can combine the values of each in the row using [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). Example:

```
rowValues[i].join(" ")
```

Also, instead of obtaining the values of each row via loop you can obtain the values of all 30 rows at one time and then loop through them, like so

```
var rowValues = sources.getRange(1, 1, 30, sources.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < 30 ; i++){ 
    Logger.log(rowValues[i].join(" "));}
```

The advantage being, lesser overhead. So faster execution of the script and overall a good practice. The rowValues will be a 2D array like so:

```
  rowValues = [["Row1Col1","Row1Col2",... ,"Row1ColLast"],
              ["Row2Col1",...,"Row2ColLast"],
              ...
              ...
              ["Row30Col1",....,"Row30ColLast"]]  // End of array
```

So when you do `rowValue[0].join(" ")` it return the following value

```
rowValue[0].join(" ") => "Row1Col1 Row1Col2 ...  Row1ColLast"
```

which is a string and can be searched using the indexOf(). So your final code would look like this:

```
function myFunction1() {

var tss = DocumentApp.openById("targetspreadsheet");
var docBody = tss.getBody();  


var sourcess =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("source spreadsheet");
var sources  = sourcess.getSheets()[0]; 


 var name = sources.getRange("A1").getValue();
 var rowValues = sources.getRange(1, 1, 30, sources.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < 30 ; i++){ 
    Logger.log(rowValues[i].join(" "));
    if (rowValues[i].join(" ").indexOf("Word1") >= 1 && rowValues[i].join(" ").indexOf("Word2") >= 1){
      Logger.log("found Text "+name)
      docBody.replaceText("TextToReplace", name)
    }
    else {
      continue;
    }  
  }


}
```

Comment: Thanks, that sound promissing! I will test it soon.

Comment: The code works perfectly. Thanks, for solving my problem and for taking your time(also to Umair). Note for someone who want to use the code: `else {
      continue;
    }` has to be set one line further to the top.

Answer (score 0):

If your code in not working [Array IndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)then try this

```
if (String(rowValues).indexOf("Word1") != -1 && String(rowValues).indexOf("Word2") != -1)
```

Notice I have changed the index condition value too. [String indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: is "-=" a typo for "!="?  I think  your answer would execute much faster than the dual loops in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you @aNewb for pointing that out. Fixed!